# Getting start and end date for an event if event ends in specified period

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Excel screenshot]

I have an excel spreadsheet where 1s represent whether a person was still contracted with a company and 0 represents that they were not. We have a 4 month reporting term and we need to find which people left within the reporting term, when they started and when they left.

In the above example, 7/1 - 10/1 would be the report dates. It would return that Person G started 5/1/2020 and ended 9/1/2020 and that Person H started 4/1/2020 and ended 8/1/2020.

I was thinking of writing a VBA script that took the reporting start date and end date as input from the user, finding any 1s within those dates, and returning the date that corresponds with the 1 in the reporting term and the first 1 in a range of consecutive 1s. Problem is that I'm not sure how to scan the row of dates with the VBA script and account for scenarios where a person started and ended in the reporting term (or started outside the reporting term and ended in the reporting term and then started and ended again within the reporting term).

Does anyone have some good suggestions for how best to go about this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using two program cases:

1. There is a (1,0) sequence, which means that the term ended.  If this pattern is detected, that means that the person ended by the second cell in that sequence.
2. There is a (0,1) sequence, which means that the term started.  If this pattern is detected, that means that the person started by the second cell in that sequence.

This can be done using a for loop that tracks the current value and last known value:

```
Dim currVal As Integer, prevVal as Integer
prevVal = 0
Dim i as Integer
For i = startColumn to endColumn
    currVal = Cells(row, i)
    If currVal = 0 And prevVal = 1 Then
    
        endDate = Cells(1,i)    

    ElseIf currVal = 1 And prevVal = 0 Then
    
        startDate = Cells(1,i)
    
    End If

    prevVal = currVal
Next i
```

Then, you would just need variables to capture the start/end dates, and to fill in which rows and columns you are processing.